# Mixed conditionals/ 2nd conditional/3rd conditional--- which should be used in the sentences given below?

Tags: conditional-constructions

> If I hadn't handed him over to the police earlier today, I
>   **wouldn't** be able to sleep tonight.
>
> If I hadn't handed him over to the police earlier today, I
>   **wouldn't have** been able to sleep tonight.
>
> If I didn't hand him over to the police earlier today, I
>   **wouldn't** be able to sleep tonight.

Are all of these sentences grammatically correct?
What are the differences in their meaning?
Since we're talking about an unreal past situation in the `if` clause, it should be **HAD**, right? And since we're talking about an unreal present/extremely near future situation, shouldn't it be **would** in the second clause?

Comment: They're all stylistically appalling (not only are the first words of the third one ungrammatical, but any normal speaker would just say *If I hadn't handed him over...* rather than *...taken him to hand over...*). And the second version is semantically problematic, since it refers to an "unreal" ***past*** situation, but in almost all credible contexts, ***tonight*** refers to a ***future*** time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that "Taken" in the third sentence was a typo. 
Of the three sentences given there, wouldn't you say the first is the most appropriate?

Comment: **What communicative need are you trying to address?**  Have you used  any of these in real life and gotten feedback from the person you were talking with? Do you speak regularly in English, preferably with a native speaker (so you can hear native pronunciation) and gotten good, intuitive  feedback)? **Which sentence do you think you'd say in any given situation?**

Comment: Have you looked up Conditional sentences in English (on Wikipedia, for instance),  and read about what they mean? What effort and research have you done?

Comment: I don't really see the point of saying which of the first two is "best" (the third is *still* ungrammatical following your edit). The fact remains normal speakers wouldn't say *If I hadn't taken him to hand him over...* As to the verb you're *really* asking about, *wouldn't have been able to* is quite unlikely if you haven't *yet* slept tonight (but I don't think that *necessarily* makes it "ungrammatical"). Plus of course, it's possible the speaker might have already slept earlier tonight, and woke up later to make the statement which would then be beyond reproach.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Okay. I edited my post. 
Which of the sentences would use now? And that's saying, you haven't already slept earlier tonight, and woke up later to make the statement which would then be beyond reproach.

Comment: @AlanCarmack, Yes. I have done some research on conditionals, and how to use them. 
And, i do get to talk to native speakers, but i don't get to do it in person. 
I do it over text on social media sites.  
I'd use the first, because it talks about an unreal past event, and an unreal future/ present event.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, sentence 1) is **grammatically correct**. You are mixing

the THIRD CONDITIONAL (if + Past Perfect  - an activity that happened  in the

past - with a Result clause containing Would + Base Form < referring to an

action that's coming in the future>.

On the contrary, I would say that the problem with sentences   2) and 3) is the

**TIME EXPRESSIONS** .Ex. If I hadn't handed him over to the police

**yesterday** morning, I wouldn't have been able to sleep **last night**. (Here,

you would be talking about a past condition and result - .

In sentence 3)  If I didn't hand him over to the police this morning, I wouldn't

be able to sleep tonight. (second conditional). I would understand that you

aren't quite sure about handing him over and perhaps, you won't do it, so you

are thinking it over.

Comment: Sentence 2) would be a typical example of the regular conditional 3.